# Retrieving Object without a Certain Variable

Tags: java, rest, object

I'm working on a small Java RESTful API and a client has asked for a certain object to have two different return options.

When a request is made to (as an example) `/api/v1/products` they want it to return just the "id" and "title" as opposed to the full object below.

When a request is then made to `/api/v1/products/[productId]` they want it to return the full object as well as any nested objects.

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int weight;
    private List<Price> prices;
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically create an object with only certain variables? They want it so that the other variables are never returned (for example in a JSON response they wouldn't want to see null values).

Am I right in thinking that the full object should be returned in the collection of products (`/api/v1/products`)?

Comment: payload size will be too much if you include all the information in the collection of products. Its probably better to return only minimal detail in the collection response and make another call to get more detail

Comment: If this is an API that returns json I'd leave all fields empty (null) that should not be returned in the call /api/v1/products and use a JSON mapper (for instance Jackson) to deal with it. You can not create a "dynamic" class, but you indeed can alter the output of your API.

Comment: Or you can have two classes: Product and ProductDetails for instance. Return the serialized version of one that's appropriate.

Comment: @Markus Thanks. This is what I had suggested to them originally but they weren't too keen on the idea in case it caused confusion. I think this is a good option.

Comment: @AbhishekDeyDas Thanks. They may end up picking this as it's along the lines of what they want.